# Como agregar soporte Maven a App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para **Google App Engine** con el IDE **Intellij IDEA**, al iniciar el nuevo proyecto este IDE permite la creación de una aplicación App Engine con la estructura por defecto.

Al terminar la creación este no cuenta con el característico pom.xml de los proyectos **Maven** y necesito hacer el control de versiones para las herramientas que utilizare en mi proyecto.

La pregunta es:

¿Como puedo agregarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecciona la raíz de tu proyecto y da click en **Add Framework Support** ahí seleccionas maven y listo, tu **pom.xml** se crea automáticamente.